# How can I add the active class to to the current <li> within bootstrap collapse navbar-collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use javascript in order to create a bootstrap `<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">` where I only have to update the javascript file rather than manage a navbar on individual pages for a website.

This is the code for the banner:

```js
document.write(
"    <div class='navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top'>" +
"        <div class='container'>" +
"            <div class='navbar-header'>" +
"                <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='.navbar-collapse'>" +
"                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>" +
"                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>" +
"                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>" +
"                </button>" +
"                <a class='navbar-brand' href='link1.aspx'>My Website</a>" +
"            </div>" +
"               <div class='collapse navbar-collapse'>" +
"                <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>" +
"                    <li><a href='link1.aspx'>Link 1</a></li>" +
"                    <li><a href='link2.aspx'>Link 2</a></li>" +
"                    <li><a href='link3.aspx'>Link 3</a></li>" +
"                    <li><a href='link4.aspx'>Link 4</a></li>" +
"                    <li><a href='link5.html'>Link 5</a></li>" +
"                    <li><a href='link6.aspx'>Link 6</a></li>" +
"                </ul>" +
"               </div>" +
"            <!--/.nav-collapse -->" +
"        </div>" +
"    </div>"
);
```

This is where I am trying to set the current page's navigation bar `<li>` to active:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".collapse navbar-collapse ul li a").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname)
            $(this).addClass("active");
    })
})
```

All code is located in a header.js file that I call from each page at the beginning to show the header:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/header.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

The problem is the code doesn't work and I don't know why. Am I declaring `$(".collapse navbar-collapse ul li a")` incorrectly? Is the way that the navigation bar setup incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *collapse* and *navbar-collapse* are in the same element you have to write

```
$(".collapse.navbar-collapse ul li a")
```

In the provided code there was no jQuery .js file included, but I assume you have that in your own code

Comment: I call the jQuery .js in the html page head, just forgot to include it in the sample html file. <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>. I tried updating to your suggestion and still not working. I did a alert(window.location.pathname); to check the path being used in the if statement and it returned /link1.aspx on the link1 page. Tried adding / to all the links and still not working.

Comment: I've created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KL6YHfs8ElPjC8YVTUgo?p=preview) that will write the href of each link found. Look at the **script.js** file (everything is written there) By the way, using plunker the window.location is not the same as on your server so that might differ when you will compare the links

Comment: Thank you for that, I was able to get all of the links to become active with this code (adding the / to the link path was key): `$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".collapse.navbar-collapse ul li a").each(function () {
            alert("found a link with href=" + $(this).attr("href"));
            if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname) {
                $(".collapse.navbar-collapse ul li").addClass("active");
            }
    })
});`. Now, I just need to know why the if statement isn't working!

Comment: Since the **window.location.pathname** at plunker isn't the same as on your server i would recommend that you change the alert to     `alert("compare: " + window.location.pathname + " with:" + $(this).attr("href"));`
Here check how the two values differ and make adjustments so that the strings will be equal. If you want you can tell me what **window.location.pathname** produces when you visit one of your links, and I might help you adjust your if-statement.

Comment: Values are the same when running the compare. I think the if statement might be adding active to all the li's because I'm running through each link and comparing the link to itself, which is always going to be true. How would I specify the link in the loop after updating to `    $(".collapse.navbar-collapse ul li").each(function () {
`?

Comment: I figured it out! This is the code that works `$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".collapse.navbar-collapse ul li").each(function () {
            //alert("found a link with href=" + $(this).attr("href"));
            alert("compare: " + window.location.pathname + " with: " + $(this).find('a').attr("href"));
            if ($(this).find('a').attr("href") == window.location.pathname) 
                $(this).addClass("active");
            
    })
});`

Answer (score 0):

You have this HTML:

```
<div class='collapse navbar-collapse'>
```

And you are using this JS:

```
$(".collapse navbar-collapse ul li a")
```

Try changing the above line to this:

```
$(".collapse ul li a")
```

...or...

```
$(".collapse.navbar-collapse ul li a")
```

---

Also, your `if` statement looks poorly structured.

Try changing this:

```
if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname)
    $(this).addClass("active");
```

To this:

```
if ($(this).attr("href") == window.location.pathname) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
}
```

---

That may or may not solve your problem, but nonetheless it should fix some errors in your code.